# How to send String value from one screen to another in Blackberry?

Tags: architecture, blackberry, screen

Anyone please help me to pass String value from one screen to another screen in Blackberry

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would say to do pushing 2nd screen from the 1st screen, not from the application.
In app push first screen:

```
public class App extends UiApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        App app = new App();
        app.enterEventDispatcher();
    }   
    public App() {
        FirstScreen scr = new FirstScreen();
        pushScreen(scr);
    }
}
```

Second screen has a setter for string value:

```
public class SecondScreen extends MainScreen {

    String mTextValue = null;
    LabelField mLabel = null;

    public void setTextValue(String textValue) {
        mTextValue = textValue;
        mLabel.setText(mTextValue);
    }

    public SecondScreen() {
        super();        
        mLabel = new LabelField();
        add(mLabel);
    }
}
```

In first screen create second, set string value and push it. Pop first screen if you don't need to return on it:

```
public class FirstScreen extends MainScreen implements FieldChangeListener {

    BasicEditField mEdit = null; 
    ButtonField mButton = null;

    public FirstScreen() {
        super();                
         mEdit = new BasicEditField("input: ", "some text");
         add(mEdit);
         mButton = new ButtonField("Go second screen");
         mButton.setChangeListener(this);
         add(mButton);
    }
    public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
        if(mButton == field)
        {
            SecondScreen scr = new SecondScreen();
            scr.setTextValue(mEdit.getText());
            UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(scr);
            UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen(this);
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you may need to be a little more clear in what you require. But taking your original question literally, the following bit of code is how you would do it.

```
public class MyApp extends UiApplication {
  MyApp() {
    MyFirstScreen screenOne = new MyFirstScreen();
    pushScreen(screenOne);
    String str = screenOne.getWhateverStringINeed();
    MySecondScreen screenTwo = new MySecondScreen(str);
    pushScreen(screenTwo);
  }
}
```

The above code would push two screens onto the BlackBerry display stack, with the second screen essentially having the string (whatever string you happen to need), from the first screen.