# How pass value one screen to another screen in blackberry?

Tags: java, blackberry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to send String value from one screen to another in Blackberry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123511/how-to-send-string-value-from-one-screen-to-another-in-blackberry)

how i can pass value(like String,int) from one screen to another screen in Blackberry.
please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Through constructor you can pass values from one screen another screen

for example 
when you click on ButtonField you can write this inside FieldChanged method

```
        int i=10;
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new Sample(i));
```

inside your Sample class you have to make one constructor you have to make like following

```
public class sample extends MainScreen{
private int i=0;
    public sample(int i) {
        this.i=i;// now you can get i value which was you pass from before screen

    }
}
```

other way is to make that value as **static** and use that value on next screen using previousScreenname.variableName

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get some values from your `current screen to the other screen` you can see this **question on stack overflow** [how-to-send-string-value-from-one-screen-to-another-in-blackberry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123511/how-to-send-string-value-from-one-screen-to-another-in-blackberry) or the other way you can make constructor of the screen having parameter of  your desired type and push the screen on the displaystack with the values you are getting on the current screen. There is also another way other way is to make that value which you want on the anotherScreen `static` and use that value on next screen using `YourPrevScreen.thatVariablename` which you have declared as static